# Wordpress shortens my NON English link too much

Tags: php, wordpress, http, url, multilingual

guys. I have installed wordpress for my blog, and I want to use Georgian language for my blog. But here the problem arises. When I post a new article my links appear too short.

For example if I want to set my link as

```
http://localhost/exampleWP/ეს-არის-უბრალოდ-ლინკი-ვორდპრესში-გამოსაყენებლად
```

it appears to be like this:

```
http://localhost/exampleWP/%E1%83%94%E1%83%A1-%E1%83%90%E1%83%A0%E1%83%98%E1%83%A1-%E1%83%A3%E1%83%91%E1%83%A0%E1%83%90%E1%83%9A%E1%83%9D%E1%83%93-%E1%83%9A%E1%83%98%E1%83%9C%E1%83%99%E1%83%98-%E1%83%95%E1%83%9D%E1%83%A0/?lang=ge
```

So wordpress thinks that link is too long and shortens it.

Can you guys give me an idea what to do?

Comment: urls aren't utf-8. They can't be or there would be security nightmares everywhere. You could register bankofamerica.com for your own phishing purposes because one of the characters isn't exactly what it looks like. More here http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the maximum slug length with wordpress is only 200 characters. This is why your link address is shortened. And in some cases doesn't actually work at all.

*Slug meaning the length of the string after exampleWP/.

Glen

Comment: So, what to do? Can there be done something to use Georgian words as URL?

Comment: Using non English words is not where your problem lies. Its the length of the non English word converted to ASCII that's your problem. For example using http://localhost/exampleWP/ეს-არის which would convert to this http://localhost/exampleWP/%E1%83%94%E1%83%A1-%E1%83%90%E1%83%A0%E1%83%98%E1%83%A1 would be perfectly acceptable. An example of something similar is hy.wikipedia.org/wiki/Գլխավոր_էջ which is read as http://hy.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D4%B3%D5%AC%D5%AD%D5%A1%D5%BE%D5%B8%D6%80_%D5%A7%D5%BB

Comment: The length of the slug will still have to be less than 200. Have a look at this for info on using UTF-8 as a URL http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2011/code/utf-8-multibyte-characters-in-url-parameters-%E2%9C%93/